# lookup the lock statistic in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I study Linux lock mechanism recently, and want to see the lock holding and waiting time.

So I turn on `CONFIG_LOCK_STAT` flag in the `.config` file via `make menuconfig` and after recompiling the kernel run the command:

```
# less /proc/lock_stat
```

I got the following message:

```
*WARNING* lock debugging disabled!! - possibly due to a lockdep warning.
```

Just don't know why, since I've turn on all the flags in the kernel `hack->lock` session.

P.S. The environment I use: kernel 3.12.6 (by `uname -a`).

***UPDATE: dmesg with `__debug_locks_off()` and `dump_stack()` on***

```
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817516a2>] _raw_write_lock+0x72/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392718>] ? irqsafe4_soft_wlock_213+0x98/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392718>] irqsafe4_soft_wlock_213+0x98/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399cd6>] locking_selftest+0x1286/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000]   ok  |  ok  |
[    0.000000]     hard-safe-A + unsafe-B #2/231:### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  0000000000000002 ffffffff81c01c38 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81c15c98
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01c48 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01d60 ffffffff810d9d1e
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01ff8 ffffffff81c00000 ffffffff81c01fe8 ffffffff824d2d58
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d9d1e>] check_usage+0x10e/0x550
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810170f4>] ? dump_trace+0x194/0x2f0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d6a54>] ? __bfs+0x24/0x240
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810da1af>] check_irq_usage+0x4f/0xc0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810dd1ae>] __lock_acquire+0x1bce/0x2190
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817511e7>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x67/0x70
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810c13b6>] ? vprintk_emit+0x1d6/0x630
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810de882>] lock_acquire+0xb2/0x160
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b936>] ? irqsafe4_hard_spin_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b870>] ? irqsafe4_hard_rlock_231+0x110/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81750e96>] _raw_spin_lock+0x46/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b936>] ? irqsafe4_hard_spin_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b936>] irqsafe4_hard_spin_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399d22>] locking_selftest+0x12d2/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000] ### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c15580 ffffffff81c01e78 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81cab258
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01e88 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01ed8 ffffffff810df539
[    0.000000]  0000000000000082 ffffffff8138b936 0000000000000092 ffffffff81cab258
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810df539>] lock_acquired+0x2f9/0x4d0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b936>] ? irqsafe4_hard_spin_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b870>] ? irqsafe4_hard_rlock_231+0x110/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81750ec2>] _raw_spin_lock+0x72/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b936>] ? irqsafe4_hard_spin_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b936>] irqsafe4_hard_spin_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399d22>] locking_selftest+0x12d2/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000]   ok  |### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  0000000000000002 ffffffff81c01c38 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81c15c98
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01c48 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01d60 ffffffff810d9d1e
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01ff8 ffffffff81c00000 ffffffff81c01fe8 ffffffff824d3138
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d9d1e>] check_usage+0x10e/0x550
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810170f4>] ? dump_trace+0x194/0x2f0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d6a54>] ? __bfs+0x24/0x240
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810da1af>] check_irq_usage+0x4f/0xc0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810dd1ae>] __lock_acquire+0x1bce/0x2190
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d80e8>] ? lockdep_init_map+0x68/0x6d0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810de882>] lock_acquire+0xb2/0x160
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392636>] ? irqsafe4_hard_wlock_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392570>] ? irqsafe4_soft_wlock_231+0xf0/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81751676>] _raw_write_lock+0x46/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392636>] ? irqsafe4_hard_wlock_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392636>] irqsafe4_hard_wlock_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399d35>] locking_selftest+0x12e5/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000] ### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c15580 ffffffff81c01e78 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81cab058
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01e88 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01ed8 ffffffff810df539
[    0.000000]  0000000000000082 ffffffff81392636 0000000000000092 ffffffff81cab058
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810df539>] lock_acquired+0x2f9/0x4d0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392636>] ? irqsafe4_hard_wlock_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392570>] ? irqsafe4_soft_wlock_231+0xf0/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817516a2>] _raw_write_lock+0x72/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392636>] ? irqsafe4_hard_wlock_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392636>] irqsafe4_hard_wlock_231+0xc6/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399d35>] locking_selftest+0x12e5/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000]   ok  |  ok  |
[    0.000000]     soft-safe-A + unsafe-B #2/231:### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  0000000000000006 ffffffff81c01c38 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81c15c98
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01c48 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01d60 ffffffff810d9d1e
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01cd8 0000000081c00000 ffffffff81c01fe8 0000000000000001
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d9d1e>] check_usage+0x10e/0x550
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d9ac2>] ? check_usage_backwards+0x72/0x1c0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d6a54>] ? __bfs+0x24/0x240
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810da1af>] check_irq_usage+0x4f/0xc0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810dd1cd>] __lock_acquire+0x1bed/0x2190
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817511e7>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x67/0x70
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810c13b6>] ? vprintk_emit+0x1d6/0x630
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810de882>] lock_acquire+0xb2/0x160
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138d6f8>] ? irqsafe4_soft_spin_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138d650>] ? irqsafe4_soft_rlock_231+0xf0/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81750e96>] _raw_spin_lock+0x46/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138d6f8>] ? irqsafe4_soft_spin_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138d6f8>] irqsafe4_soft_spin_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399d81>] locking_selftest+0x1331/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000] ### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c15580 ffffffff81c01e78 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81cab258
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01e88 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01ed8 ffffffff810df539
[    0.000000]  0000000000000282 ffffffff8138d6f8 0000000000000292 ffffffff81cab258
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810df539>] lock_acquired+0x2f9/0x4d0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138d6f8>] ? irqsafe4_soft_spin_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138d650>] ? irqsafe4_soft_rlock_231+0xf0/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81750ec2>] _raw_spin_lock+0x72/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138d6f8>] ? irqsafe4_soft_spin_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138d6f8>] irqsafe4_soft_spin_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399d81>] locking_selftest+0x1331/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000]   ok  |### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  0000000000000006 ffffffff81c01c38 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81c15c98
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01c48 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01d60 ffffffff810d9d1e
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01cd8 0000000081c00000 ffffffff81c01fe8 0000000000000001
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d9d1e>] check_usage+0x10e/0x550
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d9ac2>] ? check_usage_backwards+0x72/0x1c0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d6a54>] ? __bfs+0x24/0x240
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810da1af>] check_irq_usage+0x4f/0xc0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810dd1cd>] __lock_acquire+0x1bed/0x2190
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d80e8>] ? lockdep_init_map+0x68/0x6d0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810de882>] lock_acquire+0xb2/0x160
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392528>] ? irqsafe4_soft_wlock_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392480>] ? irqsafe4_hard_wlock_312+0x110/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81751676>] _raw_write_lock+0x46/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392528>] ? irqsafe4_soft_wlock_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392528>] irqsafe4_soft_wlock_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399d94>] locking_selftest+0x1344/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000] ### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c15580 ffffffff81c01e78 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81cab058
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01e88 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01ed8 ffffffff810df539
[    0.000000]  0000000000000282 ffffffff81392528 0000000000000292 ffffffff81cab058
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810df539>] lock_acquired+0x2f9/0x4d0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392528>] ? irqsafe4_soft_wlock_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392480>] ? irqsafe4_hard_wlock_312+0x110/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817516a2>] _raw_write_lock+0x72/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392528>] ? irqsafe4_soft_wlock_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81392528>] irqsafe4_soft_wlock_231+0xa8/0xf0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399d94>] locking_selftest+0x1344/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000]   ok  |  ok  |
[    0.000000]     hard-safe-A + unsafe-B #2/312:### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  0000000000000000 ffffffff81c01cb0 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81c15c98
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01cc0 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01d50 ffffffff810d9adf
[    0.000000]  0000000000000000 ffffffff8288dec0 ffffffff824d43a8 0000000081c01d60
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d9adf>] check_usage_backwards+0x8f/0x1c0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810da9c2>] mark_lock+0x412/0x820
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810d9a50>] ? check_usage_forwards+0x1c0/0x1c0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810dbf68>] __lock_acquire+0x988/0x2190
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817511e7>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x67/0x70
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810c13b6>] ? vprintk_emit+0x1d6/0x630
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810de882>] lock_acquire+0xb2/0x160
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b72e>] ? irqsafe4_hard_spin_312+0xde/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b650>] ? irqsafe4_hard_rlock_312+0x110/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81750e96>] _raw_spin_lock+0x46/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b72e>] ? irqsafe4_hard_spin_312+0xde/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b72e>] irqsafe4_hard_spin_312+0xde/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399de0>] locking_selftest+0x1390/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000] ### __debug_locks_off called!
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.6 #13
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Sony Corporation VGN-Z25TN_B/VAIO, BIOS R2140M3 08/26/2008
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c15580 ffffffff81c01e78 ffffffff81747f7c ffffffff81cab258
[    0.000000]  ffffffff81c01e88 ffffffff81383d27 ffffffff81c01ed8 ffffffff810df595
[    0.000000]  0000000000000282 ffffffff8138b72e 0000000000000292 ffffffff81cab258
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81747f7c>] dump_stack+0x54/0x74
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81383d27>] debug_locks_off+0x17/0x50
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff810df595>] lock_acquired+0x355/0x4d0
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b72e>] ? irqsafe4_hard_spin_312+0xde/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b650>] ? irqsafe4_hard_rlock_312+0x110/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81750ec2>] _raw_spin_lock+0x72/0x80
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b72e>] ? irqsafe4_hard_spin_312+0xde/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff8138b72e>] irqsafe4_hard_spin_312+0xde/0x110
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff817481f5>] dotest+0x43/0x5a7
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81399de0>] locking_selftest+0x1390/0x2100
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1aca9>] start_kernel+0x2d2/0x427
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a4c7>] 
[    0.000000]  [<ffffffff81f1a5d6>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x10d/0x11c
[    0.000000]   ok  |
[    0.000000] -------------------------------------------------------
[    0.000000] Good, all 253 testcases passed! |
[    0.000000] ---------------------------------
[    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered
```

Comment: `lockdep warning` is a warning about runtime lockdep checks. Grep `dmesg` output for `lockdep` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Enable lock statistics

First of all be sure to enable lock statistics collecting. From [Documentation/locking/lockstat.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/locking/lockstat.txt):

> - CONFIGURATION
>
> Lock statistics are enabled via `CONFIG_LOCK_STAT`.
>
> - USAGE
>
> Enable collection of statistics:
>
> ```
> # echo 1 >/proc/sys/kernel/lock_stat
> ```
>
> Disable collection of statistics:
>
> ```
> # echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/lock_stat
> ```
>
> Look at the current lock statistics:
>
> ( line numbers not part of actual output, done for clarity in the explanation
>        below )
>
> ```
> # less /proc/lock_stat
> ```

So, be sure to enable collection of lock statistics first.

## Check lockdep warnings in kernel log

Now, let's take a look at the code where your warning message is printing:

[kernel/locking/lockdep_proc.c : seq_header()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/locking/lockdep_proc.c#L543):

```c
if (unlikely(!debug_locks))
    seq_printf(m, "*WARNING* lock debugging disabled!! - possibly due to a lockdep warning\n");
```

This `debug_locks` variable is being set to 0 (disabled) by `debug_locks_off()` function, which is in turn can be called from a **lot** of places. Let's take a look at the place where this variable is defined:

[lib/debug_locks.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/debug_locks.c#L17):

```c
/*
 * We want to turn all lock-debugging facilities on/off at once,
 * via a global flag. The reason is that once a single bug has been
 * detected and reported, there might be cascade of followup bugs
 * that would just muddy the log. So we report the first one and
 * shut up after that.
 */
int debug_locks = 1;
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(debug_locks);
```

Comment for that variable explain why you see that warning.

So check your kernel log (via `dmesg` command) for actual found bugs by `lockdep` mechanism. You will probably find one, which will explain why lock debugging is disabled.

## UPDATE

Regarding this message:

> [ 0.084000] SMP alternatives: lockdep: fixing up alternatives

It seems like it has nothing to do with your actual issue. This message is printing by next code:

[arch/x86/kernel/alternative.c : alternatives_enable_smp()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/alternative.c?v=3.12#L405):

```c
#ifdef CONFIG_LOCKDEP
   /*
    * Older binutils section handling bug prevented
    * alternatives-replacement from working reliably.
    *
    * If this still occurs then you should see a hang
    * or crash shortly after this line:
    */
   pr_info("lockdep: fixing up alternatives\n");
#endif
```

This code is old and obsolete, and it's dropped in newer kernel versions by this commit:

[lockdep, x86/alternatives: Drop ancient lockdep fixup message](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2a929242ee50db84c1a561c81897bb0551f2c32f)

So I think it's something else that leads to disabling of collecting lock statistics. It's hard to tell what exactly though. The only thing I can think of is to modify kernel so that you can see what caused disabling of lock debug, rebuild kernel and look into the kernel log to figure out, where lock debug disabling was called from.

So, if you are up to this, modify [__debug_locks_off()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/debug_locks.h?v=3.12#L14) function as follows:

```c
static inline int __debug_locks_off(void)
{
    /* ---- Add this code ---- */
    pr_err("### __debug_locks_off() called!\n");
    dump_stack();
    /* ----------------------- */

    return xchg(&debug_locks, 0);
}
```

Also, add `#include <linux/printk.h>` line at the top of that file, just in case.

Then rebuild your kernel, run it and provide the whole `dmesg` output. It should be enough to tell where it's been disabled.

## UPDATE 2

As I can see from backtraces you provided, all the `dump_stack()` calls (that you added to `__debug_locks_off()` function) -- they called from `locking_selftest()` function, which is in turn just some unit testing routine. Let's take a look at it: [locking_selftest()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/locking-selftest.c?v=3.12#L1795). What is important to notice here is this code:

```c
} else {
    printk("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printk("Good, all %3d testcases passed! |\n",
        testcase_successes);
    printk("---------------------------------\n");
    debug_locks = 1;
}
```

So you can see that in your case you have `debug_locks` variable enabled ("on") in the end of the `locking_selftest()`. Taking into the account that all the messages you provided were actually triggered from `locking_selftest()` I can say that those messages couldn't lead to your issue (which is disabled `debug_locks` variable).

So you still need to figure out, where and why (in your case) this `debug_locks` variable is disabled. Let's start with this: please share complete `dmesg` output with us (you can use some pastebin service and just add the link to your question or as new comment). You may overlooked some `__debug_locks_off()` call in your `dmesg` output which was actually relevant (not called from that self-testing routine).

Comment: Thanks for you two'a help,

Comment: Dmesg and veep lockstep, got the message : SMP alternatives: lockdep:fixing up alternatives. I can't see any strange here?

Comment: Please provide complete `dmesg` output.

Comment: provided the dmesg output~~ Thanks!

Comment: I added the **UPDATE** section to my answer. Hope it addresses your issue.

Comment: Hello Sam, I update the kernel message as what you said. But the log is too big, I can't put all of them on the edit board. there seems a cycle pattern in the dmesg, so I just take some of them which correlated to __debug_locks_off.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Uz3VftTB   This is all the dmesg message, but I just see the debug_locks_off call by this pattern?

Comment: I don't see your initial warning (`*WARNING* lock debugging disabled!! - possibly due to a lockdep warning`) in the log provided. Please run the whole use-case (including reading from `/proc/lock_stat` file), and only then save `dmesg` output and share it with us. The problem may be somewhere between system start and your `lock_stat` reading.

Comment: Actually I got another problem ... when I try to dump the log. After entering my login password, it automatically reboot, and I cannot enter the ubuntu desktop. The log I provide above is by using root shell in recovery mode. Since this is off-topic of this original problem, I open to another thread https://superuser.com/questions/970743/linux-automatically-reboot-after-entering-my-password

Comment: Well, if it's happening on unchanged kernel, maybe it's another problem. But maybe code you added led somehow to kernel panic or whatever it is which in turn led to reboot.

Comment: Also, as matter of this topic, you can press Ctrl-Alt-F1, login in virtual terminal, and then do `dmesg >log.txt` there.

Comment: Yes, the newly provided dmesg provided here is by crtl-alt-F1.

Comment: I mean, you can login in Ctrl-Alt-F1 terminal, and then do `less /proc/lock_stat` to obtain original warning, and **after that** you can obtain `dmesg` log, which may contain something helpful, so we can tell why you're having this issue in the first place.

Comment: Hi Sam, I know what you mean. This link pastebin.com/y776BtaU mentioned in my above comment is obtained by login with cltr-alt-F1 terminal, and do the less /proc/stat_lock

Comment: So you had the original `*WARNING*` message in that case? Or no? I just don't see it in your `dmesg` output, so I assume it just printed to your terminal when reading `stat_lock` file, correct?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. However today I test another computer, with same kernel version. But in make menuconfig, I disable a lock self_test flag. Then after reboot, I can use lock_stat on that computer. I'll try that config on my computer and test again

Comment: Actually, I had another question... when I rebuild the kernel. I don't do make clean, but only with make bzImage, make modules , and make modules_install. After reboot, linux cannot find my USB device. But if I do make clean at first ,it turns out to be ok.

Comment: My description is a little vague. I will do some experiments, and If cannot figure out I will post the kernel log as another thread. Also will update about this lock statistic issue on this thread. Many thanks for your help~

Comment: I guess I answered your question on USB issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32502977/3866447). Look for my **NOTE** where I explain that `modules_install` rule must be run before `install`.

Comment: Still not work... I update the kernel log here: http://pastebin.com/x3m389qb   however I didn't add debug message in this version, will update the new version if rebuild is OK~~

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You mean, kernel crashes, or lock statistics can't be shown?

Comment: I mean the lock_stat is not work. And yesterday I try to add the debug message and dump_stack. After recompiling, the system cannot login...just like what I say before.

Comment: The thing is, you need this debug code only for investigating lock stat issue. So you can just use virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1) for this purpose and not actually try to login to your graphical environment session. As for lock_stat issue: I still can't see any suspicious in logs you provided rather than printings from `locking_selftest()`. The only strange thing is deadlock you are having (in the last log you posted in comments). Is this deadlock leading to reboot (on login attempt)? Or it's just printed when you are trying to read `lock_stat`?

Comment: But the log I provide before[the auto reboot log ] is that one... The dead lock is the phenomenon after I login

Comment: Strange then... `debug_locks` variable is being set to `0` somewhere (it's why you are having your original warning and it's the root cause of issue you are having). But my debug code didn't seem to help to reveal the exact place in code where it's happening... It also may be changed explicitly by assignment (`debug_locks = 0;`) and my debug patch surely can't catch such a situation... I'll try to reproduce your issue on my home PC, will come back to you after weekend, I guess :)

Comment: Sam,, thank you so much. I use the auto reboot kernel, and find that at crtl-alt-F1 terminal will be ok. So I think maybe it is turning off when I login. I will post the log  again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `CONFIG_PROVE_RCU_REPEATEDLY=y` which means "don't disable `PROVE_RCU` on first splat"