# What is the most efficient and elegant way develop/debug linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Recently I start to develop the linux device driver,

I face a problem, when I want to debug with kernel code, and add some `printk` debug message in the kernel file.

for example, recently I add some `printk()` and `dump_stack()` in the `__debug_locks_off()` which resides in `include/linux/debug_locks.h`.

Then I do the following steps, which is very time consuming.

```
make clean
make bzImage
make modules
make modules_install
mkinitrfmfs -o /boot/initrd.img 3.12.6[my kernel version] 
cp arch/x86/boot/bzImage /boot
update-grub
```

Then reboot and choose my new kernel version.

I don't know if there are some redundant steps?
Any guideline or help will be appreciate.

Comment: In the most cases, `make clean` is not needed for recompile kernel after some changes: kernel build system (and `make` itself) is clever enough to compile only those files, which depends on changed sources.

Comment: So other steps still needs to do, except the make clean step?

Comment: If you do not change function's signatures, you can also skip `make modules` and `make modules_install` steps. Other steps are not so time-consuming (except `make bzImage`, of course, but it is mandatory).

Comment: I don't know whether my understanding is right. So even if the function is defined in the header file, if I don't change the signature, I don't need to do make modules and modules install?

Comment: Another idea is to run your OS in a VM while debugging, then you don't have to reboot your machine and can continue working.

Comment: @AnakinTung: Hmm, actually this is depends on static function, which body you change. E.g., `__debug_locks_off` is not for use by modules, so you needn't to rebuild modules after changing it. In any case, you can try to reboot with unmodified modules (that is, skip `make modules` and `make modules_install`). The worst thing you get is that modules doesn't receive your changes.

Comment: Yeah... That's one of thing I am curious, how can I know which module will be impact if I change the header file? Can I figure out it from Makefile?

Comment: @AnakinTung Just do `make modules` and `make modules_install` each time, but **don't** do `make clean`. This way you will rebuild only those modules that depend on changes you made to sources. Also, consider using `-j` option for `make`, which can make build faster (like `make -j4 modules`). Also, consider [using `ccache` tool for kernel building](http://linuxdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-ccache-to-speed-up-kernel.html).

Comment: And if you develop the device driver not the core part of kernel itself, you can compile it as module. Then you don't have to reboot, just unload module, recompile it with kernel build system and load again in kernel.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. You really give me lots of help. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: Hello Just, I know that~~~ thanks

Comment: @AnakinTung You don't have to do 3 last commands, just do `make install` instead of them. Also see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my notes on how to build and run the custom kernel.

### Obtaining sources

Linus Torvalds' tree is [1].

It's marked as "mainline" on [2].

To clone it use information from [1]:

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```

Now go to `linux/` dir and checkout on master branch (we need to use most recent
changes as starting point for development):

```
$ cd linux
$ git checkout master
```

Before actual development don't forget to update your branch:

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

### Building

Kernel version on my machine:

```
$ uname -r

3.16.0-4-amd64
```

To obtain config from the system running on my machine:

```
$ cp /boot/config-`uname -r` ./.config
```

To update my config (with default answers) I used next command:

```
$ make olddefconfig
```

To disable (to not build) modules which are not loaded in my current system:

```
$ make localmodconfig
```

To answer all questions with default answer, I just clicked <kbd>Enter</kbd> until finish
(just two times actually).

Next I did:

```
$ make menuconfig
```

and chose next config options:

```
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-joe"
```

Setting up ccache and build environment:

```
$ ccache -C
$ ccache -M 4G
$ export CC="ccache gcc"
```

Build kernel (using `ccache`):

```
$ reset
$ make -j4
$ make -j4 modules
```

Built kernel image is:

```
arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage
```

### Installing

Installing modules for your kernel:

```
$ sudo make modules_install
```

Installing new kernel:

```
$ sudo make install
```

Installed modules reside at `/lib/modules/*-joe/kernel/`.

Installed kernel files reside at `/boot/*joe*`:

```
- config-*joe*
- initrd.img-*joe*
- System.map-*joe*
- vmlinuz-*joe*
```

`update-grub` was run as part of `make install` script, so no need to run it
manually.

**NOTE**: `modules_install` must be run **before** `install`, because `install` rule is needed for populating initramfs image with modules.
Check size of `/boot/initrd.img-*joe*` file: it must be >= 15 MiB
(if it's smaller, chances are modules are not in there).

### Start custom built kernel

Usually your custom kernel should have version bigger than your distro kernel,
so custom kernel should be run by default. If no, read further.

Reboot, go to GRUB, select next entries:

```
-> Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux
  -> Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.0.0-rc7-joe-00061-g3259b12
```

### Make your distro kernel load by default

Since video may not work in your custom kernel (video drivers must be
rebuild for this), you may want make distro kernel be loaded by default by GRUB.

For this just edit `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

and change line

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

to

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>3"
```

where `"1>3"` means:
  - go to 2nd line in GRUB, enter
  - and boot using 4th line.

After this run:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

NOTE: do not edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file as it's auto-generated and will
      be replace after each `update-grub` command.

### Removing custom kernel

If you don't need your custom kernel anymore, you may want to remove it.
To remove installed kernel, do next.

1. Remove all files installed to /boot:

   ```
   $ sudo rm -f *joe*
   ```
2. Remove all modules installed:

   ```
   $ sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/*joe*
   ```
3. Update GRUB:

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```

### Cleaning up built kernel

If you don't need to do incremental build and want to do clean build instead
(e.g. you made checkout to another version), you may want to clean your built
files first:

```
$ make -j4 distclean
```

### Links

[1] https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/

[2] https://kernel.org/

[3] http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/KernelCompilation

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier,the only step that is redundant and is also time consuming is "make clean" if you are recompiling the kernel. kernel build system uses Makefiles to build which in turn follows incremental build procedure i.e. the build system compares the last recent build time of the source files and their respective object files and if timestamp of a source file happens to be more recent than its object file,then the source file is compiled again else skipped.Where as "make clean" removes all the previous build outputs and make the kernel modules ready to be built from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

1. use `ccache`; this speeds up subsequent builds significantly
2. boot over network; bootloader of embedded devices have usually some tftp download mechanism; for PC you can use PXE boot
3. place the modules on an NFS root filesystem which gets filled by `make modules-install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$nfs-root`
4. when you work on a single driver only, you can build only this by `make -C $kernelsources M=$driverpath`