# How to change Linux kernel version?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I downloaded the source code for the Linux Kernel, but can not find where to change the kernel version. Help plz..
I want set version to 10, without dots 10.0.5

```
uname -s
Linux 10
```

I try modify Makefile:

```
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 2
SUBLEVEL = 78
EXTRAVERSION =
NAME = Saber-toothed Squirrel
```

to:

```
VERSION = 10
EXTRAVERSION =
NAME = Saber-toothed Squirrel
```

It compiled good, when I try to load kernel there is error
   [image]

Comment: Most likely you forgot to do `make modules_install` **before** `make install`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32502977/3866447) answer for details. Also, changing `Makefile` may be considered as bad practice. Please use some config option like `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION` to append some suffix to kernel name.

Comment: More specifically, the reason for that error is that your [initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs) probably tries to load kernel module for your disk file system (probably ext4), so that it can mount real rootfs (from your disk) and run actual `init`. And because it can't find such module, you see `Gave up on waiting for root device` error and `Missing modules` as potential cause. Hence you stuck in initramfs shell (BusyBox).

Comment: @SamProtsenko I dont need to append something to version. I need change all. When I change 
VERSION = 7
PATCHLEVEL = 2
SUBLEVEL = 78
it works good. But uname  show 7.2.78, i want it to show just 7

Comment: I doubt you can do that. Kernel `Makefile` seems to be hardcoded to use `PATCHLEVEL` and `SUBLEVEL`, and all that you can do is to set those constants to 0. Why do you want to do that anyway? What do you **actually** want to achieve by doing that?