# linux kernel build for Zedboard

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, arm, xilinx

I am working on Zedboard (Zync series FPGA FROM Xilinx) and trying to build mine kernel. So here is mine snippet of mine script:

```bash
echo -e "\e[0;32m---- Build kernel -----------\e[0m"
source ~/architech_sdk/architech/zedboard/toolchain/environment-nofs
make LOADADDR=0x8000 uImage 
echo -e "\e[0;32m---- Build modules ---\e[0m"
make modules
```

I have the `.config` file for mine Zedboard. The problem is this moment I am calling `make modules` it is giving me a lot of option and asking to put yes or no for each of one. I am very new to linux and i do not know about those options. What is way out?

Comment: Your snippet is almost unreadable, please edit your question. Otherwise, people might refuse even to look at it.

Comment: Usually you need to run something like `make ARCH=arm your_board_defconfig` before running `make`. But if you want to reuse ready `.config` for your board, you need to run `make ARCH=arm olddefconfig` before. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32502977/3866447) answer for details.

Comment: I followed this [guide](https://homepages.laas.fr/cfoucher/drupal/sites/homepages.laas.fr.cfoucher/files/u93/Installing_Embedded_Linux_on_ZedBoard.pdf) when I tried to build my custom Linux kernel. Note that, it has an automatic procedure which uses the scripts provided and will not give you complete control. I modified the scripts as per my requirement using the manual procedure in the guide. For more information check this [link](https://homepages.laas.fr/cfoucher/drupal/zedboard-development)